# Why sum of sigmoids is a good approximation of softplus function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation, approximation

According to this paper:
[Rectified Linear Units Improve Restricted Boltzmann Machines](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/icml2010_NairH10.pdf),

$\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma(x-i+\tfrac{1}{2}) \approx \log(1+e^x)$ (equation 7)

where $\sigma(z) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$

Would anyone please explain me why it is so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approximation was probably obtained thanks to two integrals encircling the sum (supposed with $N$ large enough), as shown in attachment :

[image]

In addition, the figure below shows the relative deviation as a function of $x$

[image]

Comment: The first two inequalities are wrong, it should be exactly the reverse.

Answer (score 2):

The sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sigma(x-i+1/2)$ is precisely the Riemann sum for the integral

$$\int_{1/2}^{\infty} \sigma(x-y+1/2)\,dy = \log(1+e^x)$$

using the midpoint rule with subintervals of length $\Delta x = 1$.